# Show message if length of array is 0 in Angular 5

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have a search script that a user may search persons etc. I want to display a message if what he or types doesn't exist in the array. By default, I display some results and it displays the desired person when one writes on `searchbar`. but I want to show a message if what the user writes on `searchbar` doesn't much the array. the `ngfor` works perfectly I just can't show the message.

I did a `ngIf` but doesn't show the #noThings when I type for example djlsklkssk.

Note that `userSet` always has length > 0 because I call the API anyway.

```
<ion-searchbar style="height: 30px" showCancelButton="focus" cancelButtonText="Custom Cancel" animated placeholder="Search Rovespier" [(ngModel)]="terms"></ion-searchbar>

<ion-card *ngFor="let item of userSet | search : terms">
    <div *ngIf="item; else noThings">
        {{}item.name}}
    </div>
</ion-card>
<ng-template #noThings>
    <div>
        No Result
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

.ts

```
userSet: any = [];

constructor() {
    this.searchSet();
}

searchSet() {
    this.userData.searchUser()
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {

            if (data.success) {
                this.userSet = data.searchDetails; // then it is uid_fk
            }
        });
}
```

pipe

```
import {
    Pipe, PipeTransform
}
from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'search',
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(items: any[], terms: string): any[] {
        if (!items) return [];
        if (!terms) return items;
        terms = terms.toLowerCase();
        return items.filter(it => {

            if (it.group_name) {
                return it.group_name.toLowerCase().includes(terms);
            } else if (it.username || it.title) {
                var match_username = it.username ? it.username.toLowerCase().includes(terms) : false;
                var match_title = it.title ? it.title.toLowerCase().includes(terms) : false;
                return match_username || match_title;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do, is to filter your results. Worth reading is: **[No FilterPipe or OrderByPipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)** where angular team has omitted these pipes, and recommends:

> The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly recommend moving filtering and sorting logic into the component itself. The component can expose a `filteredHeroes` or `sortedHeroes` property and take control over when and how often to execute the supporting logic. Any capabilities that you would have put in a pipe and shared across the app can be written in a filtering/sorting service and injected into the component.

So I would suggest to move this to a service if you need it for many components, otherwise you can handle that in the component, like the simple sample I give you here:

When receiving the data, you assign the array values to two arrays, one original and one for filtering, for example:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.getData().subscribe((data: Todo[]) => {
    this.todos = data;
    // this we will display in template
    this.filteredTodos = data;
  });
}
```

And in your search bar, you call a function, for example called `search`, to which you pass the value user has entered:

```ts
search(term) {
  this.filteredTodos = this.todos.filter(todo => {
    return todo.title.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
  })
}
```

Then in template you can just then check the length of the `filteredTodos` array and display `No results` if the length is `0`:

```html
<input [ngModel]="term"  (ngModelChange)="search($event)"/>

<ul *ngIf="filteredTodos.length; else noThings">
    <li *ngFor="let todo of filteredTodos">
        {{ todo.title }}
    </li>
</ul>

<ng-template #noThings>
    <div>
        No Result
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-85lpqm?file=src/app/app.component.ts)** sample for the above code.